Unable to fetch and update data due to infinite useEffect loop
i'm using React and Firestore so that users can fill out a form, submit it and find the data when they return.
Users are able to submit the form and i'm able to display the data but when updating the document is the problem.
export default function StudioName({ addData, vehicle, docReady }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState("");
  const [dataId, setDataId] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (docReady) {
      setData(vehicle.name);
    }
  }, [docReady, vehicle]);  //vehicle causes an infinite loop

  useEffect(() => {
    addData(dataId, data);
  }, [addData, dataId, data]);

  const onChange = (e) => {
    const { id, value } = e.target;

    setData(value);
    setDataId(id);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="m-5" onChange={onChange}>
        <label className="">
          <span className="mr-2">Vehicle Name</span>
          <input
            className="border-b-2 border-t-0 border-l-0 border-r-0 focus:border-b focus:ring-0 focus:border-orange-400 border-orange-400"
            required
            type="text"
            id="name"
            value={data}
          />
        </label>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

The first useEffect causes an infinite loop which prevents any update and if remove it, React will say that there's a missing dependency.
Please advise.

Using React and Firestore. Infinite loop in useEffect when updating document.
useEffect(() => {
  if (docReady) {
    setData(vehicle.name);
  }
}, [docReady]);  // remove vehicle from dependencies

Problem: First useEffect cause infinite loop. Fix: Remove vehicle dependency.
Now update works. React no complain about missing dependency.

This might not be the perfect answer, but I've found in React that there are many times a "missing dependency" won't quite be accurate or necessary to add. Are you using create-react-app or something based off of it? I think you can probably not worry about it.
It's really hard to say based off of the code that you've posted. It would help a lot to know the entire codebase, although I can imagine that might take a lot of effort...
